# Which version to use for Google Cast web/javascript sender app?

Tags: javascript, chromecast

If I look at the docs of Google Cast I'm confused as to which version I should use if I want to build a web/javascript sender app:
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/sender_apps

Under "Develop Chrome sender app" the normal docs use v1. There is a link for v2 but that has a "deprecated" badge.

For Android and iOS, there's also talk of the CAF version but nothing is available for the web?

I also had a look at Google Play Music's web client. It loads the v1 library.

Comment: You may follow the [Develop Chrome Sender App](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender_setup) for developing with the Cast Application Framework (CAF) for Chrome. The `deprecated badge in Develop with Cast v2` that you've seen means that you need to [migrate Sender App from Cast SDK v2 to the Cast Application Framework (CAF)](https://developers.google.com/cast/v2/ccl_migrate_sender).

Comment: Yes but I can't find the CAF version for javascript? Am I overlooking something?